# What is Difference between using C1 > '42' and C1>42 in check constraint in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server

I am adding check *constraint* to column like below. I am getting different results with both ways of using it. Can anybody explain what makes the difference?

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[state] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [chk_State_partition_42] CHECK ([Code]>='42' AND [Code]<'43')

ALTER TABLE dbo.State WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [chk_state_partition_42] CHECK ([code]>=42 AND [code]<43)
```

--Actually above second query is result of following dynamic sql code
DECLARE @code varchar(2) = '42'
    , @SQLStr varchar(max)
  --SET @SQLStr = 'ALTER TABLE dbo.state  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [chk_state_partition_'+@APIState+'] CHECK  ([code]>='+@APIState+' AND [code]<'+CAST(CAST(@code as int)+1 as varchar(2))+')'
 Select @SQLStr

Comment: What is the data type of [Code] and [apistate]?

Comment: One is a string, the other an integer. While 5 <= 40, '5' > '40'. You don't want to be mixing up types.

Comment: If you mix data types, data type precedence kicks in and forces a conversion (here, to int)

Comment: Actually when use second one ,constraint getting created but ,while running alter switch statement ;;Following is the Error msg

Comment: ALTER TABLE SWITCH statement failed. Table 'state' has a column level check constraint 'chk_state_partition_42' on column 'code' that is not loadable for semantic validation.

Comment: The `alter table switch` that, up until these comments, we had no knowledge of? There might be a reason why we weren't mentioning it.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server is able to cast some types implicitly [Find details here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530.aspx)

This depends on the datatype of your column `Code`. Is it numeric (e.g. `INT`), the engine will cast the `42` to a number implicitly. If not, the comparison will be done on string level.

You must be aware, that alphanumerical comparison would - probably - not work as expected. `9` is higher than `42` in this case...

### UPDATE

You just added, that the data type of your `code` column is varchar... If you **expect** a comparison of numbers, the code with qoutes `>'42'` is dangerously wrong!

Comment: You mean using  >'42' ?.Actaully second query is result of Dynamcic sql code

Comment: @user6355550 Thx a lot! Yes, of course... The text was clear, but not the code... edited it...